# Unable to install kali linux dual boot on windows 7 32 bits

Tags: kali-linux, dual-boot, uefi, secure-boot

> sorry for english grammar mistake.
> I know that for dual boot secure boot must be disable to install other OS. My pc have not secure boot option so i unable to install kali os .
> when we want to install kali and click to graphical install it terminate the installation of kali and start the windows 7 ?
> please give troubleshoot. [image][image][image][image][image]

Answer (score -1):

You need to format the disk to ext4 and create partition table.

Becarefull when chosing the partition.

Comment: I think above proble arise main cause is secure boot not found .

Comment: why i format ext4 ? I have already 50GB free unallocated spaces

Comment: Formatting a disk seems drastic and unrelated to secure boot.